# R webshot package not capturing everything

Tags: r, html, capture

The page at this link in the webshot command includes ovals to indicate air quality in a particular location

```
webshot("https://www.purpleair.com/map?&zoom=12&lat=39.09864026298141&lng=-108.56749455168722&clustersize=27&orderby=L&latr=0.22700642752714373&lngr=0.4785919189453125", "paMap.png")
```

The png that webshot produces doesn't include these ovals. I suspect these are created with javascript and webshot is not picking them up. But I don't know how to tell it to do so, or even if it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Although this issue is not directly related with webshot versions, you should consider to try webshot2 on https://github.com/rstudio/webshot2 instead of using webshot. I have prepared a blog post including various details about webshot2. You can see the details from [here](http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/export-save-r-graphs-with-webshot/). In addition, see [my detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61347676/datalabels-in-r-highcharter-cannot-be-seen-after-print-as-png-or-jpg/61479575#61479575) about the issues on webshot compared to webshot2.

I have replicated your scenario with webshot2 and delay parameter, the issue is resolved as below screenshot. The main issue is related with delay side. Basically, the URL needs a longer delay for all assets to display.

**The code**

```
library(webshot2)

temp_url = "https://www.purpleair.com/map?&zoom=12&lat=39.09864026298141&lng=-108.56749455168722&clustersize=27&orderby=L&latr=0.22700642752714373&lngr=0.4785919189453125"
webshot(url = temp_url, file = "paMap.png", delay = 4)
```

**The output file**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "192.168.99.100", port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate("https://www.purpleair.com/map?&zoom=12&lat=39.09864026298141&lng=-108.56749455168722&clustersize=27&orderby=L&latr=0.22700642752714373&lngr=0.4785919189453125")
remDr$screenshot(file = "paMag.png")
```

effect:

[image]

Comment: RSelenium and several of its dependencies are no longer on CRAN. I found them on GitHub and installed them, but.. see next comment.

Comment: The `remDr$open` code returns Error in checkError(res) : 
  Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10005 milliseconds.

Comment: I have set up rselenium with the use of Docker and that manual: https://ropensci.github.io/RSelenium/articles/RSelenium-docker.html

`$ docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0`
`$ docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0`

and after that run the R code

Comment: I'm working on a mac. I used the docker commands in a shell and they seemed to work fine. But I'm still getting the timeout error message when I run the R command `remDr$open`, both in a shell and in RStudio. Does it matter than that the standalone seems to be associated with firefox and I don't have that on my mac? My docker version is 18.03.1-ce-mac65 (24312).

Comment: it may be, use the pull command

`$ docker pull selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.0`

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium

Comment: Isn't this the same as the pull command in the previous comment. FYI, I now have both chrome and firefox on my mac.

Comment: what is a result when you sent this into terminal?

`$ docker ps`

Comment: CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES